# Tensorflow equivalent of Theano's dimshuffle

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano

How can I find the Tensorflow equivalent of Theano's dimshuffle function.

```
mask = mask.dimshuffle(0, 1, "x")
```

I'm doing this I have tried many ways but couldn't find. Thank you :)

Comment: Note: The same question with some more content is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163789/theano-dimshuffle-equivalent-in-googles-tensorflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#transpose):

```
 mask = tf.transpose(mask, perm=[0, 1])
```