# Keras implementation of Siamese like network sharing layers

Tags: python, keras

I try to implement the network architecture here: [Architecture of the network I try to implement (from Zhenyu et.al. 2019)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFx6J.png) using Keras framework with Tensorflow backend.

The network is a Siamese like network with shared layers Conv1,Conv2,Conv3. The aim is to adapt domains between 2 different inputs but that is currently not the problem, I am stuck before this. the problem is that I am facing the problem that I can not implement the model.

So my currently defined model is the following:

Define input layers for both inputs (source,target):

```
source_domain_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 160, 1),name="SourceDomainInput")
target_domain_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 160, 1),name="TargetDomainInput")
```

Then I defined the shared layer part (Conv1,Conv2 and Conv3) - for shortening the example i removed the pooling layers:

```
model_shared_part = keras.models.Sequential()
model_shared_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=16,
                                                                       kernel_size=3,
                                                                       activation='relu'),
                                                   input_shape=(None, None, 160, 1)))

model_shared_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32,
                                                                       kernel_size=3,
                                                                       activation='relu')))

model_shared_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                                                                       kernel_size=3,
                                                                       activation='relu')))
```

Then I connected the inputs to the shared layers to become the Siamese (parallel) structure:

```
featureOutput_conv3_target = model_shared_part(target_domain_input)
featureOutput_conv3_source = model_shared_part(source_domain_input)
```

Then I added the remaining layers to the source part (upper branch in the image) for shortening the example I only added some layers not all:

```
model_source_single_part = keras.models.Sequential()

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                                                                              kernel_size=3,
                                                                              activation='relu'),
                                                         )
                            )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)
                                                          )
                             )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Flatten()
                                                         )
                            )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=60)
                            )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.Dense(100,
                                                activation='relu')
                             )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=4,
                                                activation='softmax'
                                               )
                            )

final_source_layer = model_source_single_part(featureOutput_conv3_source)
```

Then I merged the created architecture to the final model:

```
dwcDAN_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[source_domain_input,
                                          target_domain_input],
                                  outputs = final_source_layer
                                  )

# Model compilation
dwcDAN_model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But the model plot gives the following:

[Model Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsVa6.png)

What I expected was that the sequential model, named sequential_2 which is the shared layer part, is connected to both inputs. but instead it is only connected to the source input.

How can I find the error in my implementation above?

Comment: What you want yo do with `featureOutput_conv3_target`? In a Siamese network, distance or similarity is calculated (using some measure like euclidean distance) between extracted feature vector of source and target. However you have just extracted feature from target but haven't used later. I guess you want to perform some operation (e.g. similarity measure) between `featureOutput_conv3_target` and `featureOutput_conv3_source` and afterwards you may want to pass that fused feature to `model_source_single_part(fused_feature)` instead of `model_source_single_part(featureOutput_conv3_source)`.

Comment: dear @bit01 thanks for your reply. My aim is the following. I want to calculate the maximum mean discrepancy between the feature output of the both layers. Therefore i am searching for a way to calculate the MMD and calculate the final loss with respect to the MMD value. So that not only the predicted cross entropy from the softmax classifier is used to optimize but also the MMD value. With this i aim to reduce the domain discrepancy. Can you help me please?

Comment: please share the reference paper link.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is pretty simple. Concat `featureOutput_conv3_source` and `featureOutput_conv3_target` and use this concatenated feature as an output along with your `final_source_layer`. Now you may ask what will be the label for concatenated layer. well, just send any dummy value since it will never be used. I'm giving an outline bellow. Please check the shape of concatenated layer in `mmd` loss function.

```
def compute_kernel(x, y):
    x_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
    print(x_size.shape)
    y_size = tf.shape(y)[0]
    print(y_size.shape)
    dim = tf.shape(x)[1]*tf.shape(x)[2]*tf.shape(x)[3]
    print(dim.shape)
    tiled_x = tf.tile(tf.reshape(x, tf.stack([x_size, 1, dim])), tf.stack([1, y_size, 1]))
    print(tiled_x.shape)
    tiled_y = tf.tile(tf.reshape(y, tf.stack([1, y_size, dim])), tf.stack([x_size, 1, 1]))
    print(tiled_y.shape)
    ret =  tf.exp(-tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tiled_x - tiled_y), axis=2) / tf.cast(dim, tf.float32))
    print(ret.shape)
    return ret


def mmd(y_true, y_pred):
    print(y_pred.shape)
    #FEATURE_LENGTH = int(y_pred.shape[3]/2) # length of each is 64
    x1 = y_pred[:,:,:,:64]  # x1 represents feature output of conv3 from source
    x2 = y_pred[:,:,:,64:] # x2 represents feature output of conv3 from source
    x1x1 = compute_kernel(x1, x1)
    x1x2 = compute_kernel(x1, x2)
    x2x2 = compute_kernel(x2, x2)
    diff = keras.backend.mean(x1x1) - 2 * keras.backend.mean(x1x2) + keras.backend.mean(x2x2)
    return diff


model_shared_part = keras.models.Sequential()
model_shared_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=16,
                                                                       kernel_size=3,
                                                                       activation='relu'),
                                                   input_shape=(5, 160, 1)))

model_shared_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32,
                                                                       kernel_size=3,
                                                                       activation='relu')))

model_shared_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                                                                       kernel_size=3,
                                                                       activation='relu')))


source_domain_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(5, 160, 1),name="SourceDomainInput")
target_domain_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(5, 160, 1),name="TargetDomainInput")
featureOutput_conv3_target = model_shared_part(target_domain_input)
featureOutput_conv3_source = model_shared_part(source_domain_input)


feature_concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()([featureOutput_conv3_source,featureOutput_conv3_target])
print(feature_concat.shape)



model_source_single_part = keras.models.Sequential()

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                                                                              kernel_size=3,
                                                                              activation='relu'),
                                                         )
                            )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)
                                                          )
                             )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Flatten()
                                                         )
                            )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=60)
                            )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.Dense(100,
                                                activation='relu')
                             )

model_source_single_part.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=4,
                                                activation='softmax'
                                               )
                            )

final_source_layer = model_source_single_part(featureOutput_conv3_source)

print(final_source_layer.shape)


# Model build
dwcDAN_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[source_domain_input, target_domain_input], outputs = [final_source_layer, feature_concat])
dwcDAN_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=['categorical_crossentropy', mmd])

print(dwcDAN_model.summary())


x1_train = np.random.rand(100, 5, 160, 1)
x2_train = np.random.rand(100, 5, 160, 1)
y_train1 = np.eye(100, 4)
y_train2 = np.random.rand(100, 5, 154, 128)


dwcDAN_model.fit([x1_train, x2_train], [y_train1, y_train2], epochs=1, batch_size=2, validation_split=.2)
```

Comment: dear @bit01 thank you very much for your reply. If i try the snippet above i get an error.
I replaced  `r = x1.dimshuffle(0,'x',1)` with the tensorflow equivalent of theanos dimshuffle:
`r = tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(x1,[0,1]), 1)`
I am not very familar with this, so could you please verify that the replacement gives the expected result? I think so, found description here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163789/theano-dimshuffle-equivalent-in-googles-tensorflow)
If i ran the code i get the error:
`ValueError: Dimension must be 4 but is 2 for 'loss_13/concatenate_loss/...`

Comment: In your code you commented the lines, which i think cause the error, with _check with shape_ . I do not really understand what the first two lines of **mmd** function do. Could you please explain them to me? The length of y_pred respectively y_true is 4 since there are 4 classes available. I dont know what the FEATURE_LENGTH variable does? I defined it above the two lines  with 1 but i dont know what it means. Could you please explain? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `FEATURE_LENGTH = 64` (which i wanted you to understand) is the feature from last layer of `model_shared_part`. As we have concatenated source and target features just for calculating MMD, in `mmd loss function` we separated/extracted that two features back by slicing so that `x1 & x2 has same size` and calculate MMD.

Comment: thanks for your explaination, i edit your code functions but there is still a dimension mismatch, i posted it in the answer above.